# Monadic buffers in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, monads

When using `Buffers.t` in a function `f`, I often use the following pattern:

1. Create a fresh buffer or empty a previously existing buffer.
2. Pass that buffer to a function which fills it.
3. Extract the result, empty the buffer and return the result.

How can I encode this pattern in a monad?

Comment: What's this `Buffers` module? The stdlib has `Buffer`, but I assume that's not it as there's no type parameter there, just strings. If it's your own module, how about pasting some example code?

Comment: This is the `Buffer` from the standard library.  I want to write a monadic wrapper enforcing the use I described.

Answer (score 3):

### Implementation of monadic buffers

This is our implementation of monadic buffers.  It has the typical signature of a monad, the type `α MonadicBuffer.t` represents an ongoing-computation yielding a value of type `α` which can write to a buffer as a side effect.  A `unit MonadicBuffer.t` then represents a completed computation.  The monadic functions `add_string` and `add_char` can be used to write in the monadic buffer and `contents` encodes the pattern you described.

```
module MonadicBuffer : sig
  type 'a t
  val return : 'a -> 'a t
  val bind : 'a t -> ('a -> 'b t) -> 'b t
  val add_char : char -> unit t
  val add_string : string -> unit t
  val contents : int -> unit t -> string
  val lift : ('a -> 'b) -> ('a t -> 'b t)
  val ( >>= ) :'a t -> ('a -> 'b t) -> 'b t
  val ( >> ) : 'a t -> 'b t -> 'b t
end = struct

  type 'a t = Buffer.t -> 'a

  let return x =
    fun _ -> x

  let bind m f =
    fun buf -> f (m buf) buf

  let add_string s buf =
    Buffer.add_string buf s

  let add_char c buf =
    Buffer.add_char buf c

  let contents sz m =
    let buf = Buffer.create sz in
    m buf;
    Buffer.contents buf

  let lift f m =
    bind m (fun x -> return (f x))

  let ( >>= ) =
    bind

  let ( >> ) m1 m2 =
    bind m1 (fun _ -> m2)
end
```

### Monadic conversion of alists to string

As an example, let us implement the conversion of `alists` to string in that monad:

```
let rec add_alist lst =
  let open MonadicBuffer in
  match lst with
    | [] -> return ()
    | (k,v) :: tl -> add_key k v >> add_alist tl
and add_key k v =
  let open MonadicBuffer in
  return ()
  >> add_string k
  >> add_string ": "
  >> add_string v
  >> add_char '\n'
```

### Higher-order conversion of alists to string

It is interessant to compare this version with the classical higher-order solution:

```
let rec buffer_add_alist buf alist =
  match alist with
    | [] -> ()
    | (k,v) :: tl -> buffer_add_key buf k v; buffer_add_alist buf tl
and buffer_add_key buf k v =
  let open Buffer in
  add_string buf k;
  add_string buf ": ";
  add_string buf v;
  add_char buf '\n'
```

Your pattern is then enforced by the `with_buffer` higher-order function:

```
let with_buffer sz f x =
  let buf = Buffer.create sz in
  f buf x;
  Buffer.contents buf
```

At the code level, the main difference is that the monadic version does not need to pass the `buf` variable all around. At the performance level, the advantage goes to the `higher-order` version.  For what is worth, the following plot represents the execution time of each method against the size of the processed `alist` (each pair being the same, all over the place):
[image: Time plot]
This displays two very noisy structure, however a linear trend in each series is clearly distinguishable, with the monadic cas having the highest slope.